# Invalid argument in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create some file paths to create new csv file in the target folder.
My code is as follows.

```
#The original path.
path_1=r'C:\Users\hh\OneDrive - Technology, Inc\IE'

#Creating the new path with the original path.
folder_name='New Folder'
x='\\'
path_2='r'+"'"+path_1+x+folder_name+"'"

#Creating the other new path with csv file name.
import csv
csv_name='r'+"'"+path_1+x+folder_name+x+'New File.csv'+"'"

#Creating a new csv file in the target folder.
with open(csv_name, 'wb') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

I had checked the paths I created many times, and didn't find anything wrong. However, It keeps showing the error as follows.

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: "r'C:\\Users\\hh\\OneDrive - Technology, Inc\\IE\\New Folder\\New File.csv'"
```

Please help me find out what did I do wrong.

Comment: Don't you mean `path_2=path_1+x+folder_name`?  Prepending a `'r'` character does not make sense as 1) that's now how you create a raw string 2) prepending the `r` will result in a filename containing `:`, which is an invalid character for a file name on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the 'r' +
And then, if you want concatenate file path, use `os.path.join()` like this

```
import os


folder_name = r"C:/test/today"
name = "test.csv"
print(os.path.join(folder_name, name))  # C:/test/today/test.csv
```

Comment: I’d recommend using Path objects from pathlib for path concatenation. It’s very powerful. Also the raw string isn’t needed if OP uses forward slashes like you have there.

Comment: @bob Thinks for your advice, I went to check out pathlib, it's really powerful, and I'm going to use it instead of `os` to solve some of my problems.  
Finally, thank you very much

Comment: Sure thing, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

That’s not how you create r-strings. Instead of ‘r’+”’C:\SOME\PATH’”, it should be r’C:\SOME\PATH’. The r goes outside the quotes, in front of the leftmost quote. You did it right the first time but as you concatenated variables to build up the final file path, you used r-strings incorrectly, and wound up with something that isn’t a valid file path.

Answer (score 0):

The **r** should me outside the quotes.

And if u want to join path try using **"os.path.join(folderPath, fileName)"**

Example

```
import os 

folder_path = r"C:\Users\hh\OneDrive - Technology, Inc\IE"
file_name = "file.csv"

final_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
```